# How to show data only one view controller ,on click collection view cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have JSON response. I want click on collection view cell(0), cell(1), ..., etc.
data show only one view controller then i click cell.

Comment: You will get more answers if you update the ticket to include tags for `iOS` and which specific language you are using.

Comment: objective C @CarlPoole

Comment: I have multiple nsarray  ,clicked the cell pass array data on onther view controller and display ,but i want click the cell(0) ,cell(1)..data pass and display same view controller @Rob

Comment: So, you just want to segue to a destination view controller, but pass the appropriate data to it on the basis of which cell you tapped on? The simplest approach is to just have segue from the cell prototype in your storyboard to the next scene and implement a [`prepare(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) in the originating view controller to set the properties in the segue's destination view controller on the basis of which cell was tapped. I would have thought this would be covered well by any contemporary view controller programming tutorial.

Comment: Or is there some more subtle question you're trying to ask? This question is extremely unclear and is likely to be closed if you can't be far more specific about what the question is. As it is, this is far too vague and is too broad...

Comment: let me know, what you are trying @RahulSingh ? can you please update with your code?